# ng-repeat not reordering when change is made to underlying array

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-sortable

I'm using ui.sortable to display a reorderable list of items. I get my data like this:

```
    context.rules.getAll()
        .then(
            function (data) { // success
                $scope.rules = data;
                cachedRules = data.slice();
                $scope.loaded = true;
            },
            function (response) { // failure
                console.log(response);
            });
```

I use `cachedRules` so I can compare the array that is being reordered to the original and detect if a change has been made or not. My view looks like this:

```
    <tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="rules">
        <tr ng-repeat="rule in rules|orderBy:'RuleSequence'" ng-class="{'unsortable': !reorder, 'inactive': !rule.Active}">
            <td><i ng-show="reorder" class="fa fa-reorder"></i></td>
            <td>{{rule.RuleSequence}}</td>
            <td>{{rule.ProxyType}}</td>
            <td>{{rule.ProxyDesc}}</td>
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-download" title="Download CSV" ng-click="getAssignments(rule.RuleID)"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-gears" title="Edit Rule" ng-click="editRuleShow(rule)"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Whenever something is reordered, this code gets called so that `RuleSequence` (what I'm using in my OrderBy) is updated:

```
            $scope.rules.map(function (r) {
                r.RuleSequence = $scope.rules.indexOf(r) + 1;
                return r;
            });
```

And then a "Save" button becomes enabled if the order of `$scope.rules` is different from `cachedRules`. This all works perfectly.

However, I want to have a "Cancel" button that when clicked will revert the display on the page to the original order. Given that I store a copy of the original data this should be easy, I use ng-click to do `$scope.rules = cachedRules.slice();`, however the order isn't updated on the page after I do that, is stays in it's changed state even though `$scope.rules` is back to it's unchanged state. How can I get the display to revert back to its original order?

Comment: I had a very similar issue with ui-sortable. I ended up having to set the list to an empty array ( list = [] ), let angular complete whatever cycle to consume events happen, and then set it back to the new array. I did this using a timeout function. IE set to empty. Set a timeout function that sets to the proper values 500ms later. But I'm guessing there is a call of some sort in angular to say "consume all current events" or some such thing.

Comment: Tried that out, instead of `$scope.rules = cachedRules.slice();` I did `$timeout(function () { $scope.rules = []; $scope.rules = cachedRules.slice(); }, 500);` No change however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking further, it looks like `.slice()` doesn't do a deep-copy like I thought it did (my in-experience with javascript shining through). So when I did my initial get of the data, and set cachedData, the array itself wasn't a reference but the objects inside of the array still were, so when I updated them here

```
            $scope.rules.map(function (r) {
                r.RuleSequence = $scope.rules.indexOf(r) + 1;
                return r;
            });
```

It was updating both, so cachedRules would have the updated RuleSequence. When I clicked "Cancel" and set it back to cachedRules, `RuleSequence` would remain the same. So when I do a proper deep copy there with loDash

```
    context.rules.getAll()
        .then(
            function (data) { // success
                $scope.rules = data;
                cachedRules = _.cloneDeep($scope.rules);
                $scope.loaded = true;
            },
            function (response) { // failure
                console.log(response);
            });
```

Everything went off without a hitch.